# How to Read Bitbucket Wiki as RSS?

Tags: bitbucket

I know that Bitbucket offers RSS, but it only gives you the commits feed. As the wiki itself is a repository, there must be an easy way to monitor changes of the wiki from a news reader. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is nothing about it in documentation I don't think it is possible.